# Count specific strings with wildcard

Tags: powershell

How can I count specific strings in a text file with PowerShell?
(I know how I can count normal specific strings)

My plan is to count domain accounts in a log file.
The script has to search for "Domain*" but how can I do it?

Example Source Data:

> Test request Domain\User1 Test Request Domain\User1 Test Request Test Domain\User2 Test

**Excepted result:**

- Found 2 User
- User1 and User2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex to capture all users and use the `Select-Object` cmdlet with the `-unique` switch to get a unique list:

```
$yourString = 'Test request Domain\User1 Test Request Domain\User1 Test Request Test Domain\User2 Test'
$result = @([regex]::Matches($yourString, 'Domain\\([\S]+)') | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | select -Unique)
Write-Host "Found $($result.count) User"
Write-Host "$($result -join ' and ')"
```

**Output:**

```
Found 2 User
User1 and User2
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks!
Can you tell me how I can exclude service accounts starting with SA (Domain\SA_Name1) with RegEx?

Comment: Just use a negative lookahead: `Domain\\(?!SA)([\S]+)`